How to configure timeout for worker in Celery
For some reason, our project occasionally disconnects Celery from Redis.
When Redis and Celery are disconnected, we need the worker to detect that the connection has been disconnected as soon as possible (about within 10 seconds). But I haven't found a setting that can solve this problem.
Here are some of my current settings，currently there are only some broker and backend settings:
settings
Related dependencies:

celery：4.1.0.
redis（server）:3.2.10.
redis（client）:3.3.0.
kombu:4.1.0

I hope someone can tell me how to configure the worker timeout so that the worker can detect the error and start reconnecting at the agreed time, instead of using the default timeout.
